# Problem with Wine, Q4Wine, Winetricks and Playonlinux

Tags: gnome, wine, playonlinux

`OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x64 + Gnome 3.36.8`

I tried to install **PlayOnLinux** via Synaptic Package Manager, and it gave a list of software to be removed and installed. And the list of packages to be removed includes:

```
Cheese
LibreOffice-gnome
Ubuntu-desktop
Ubuntu-desktop-minimal
Ubuntu-standard
Ubuntu-minimal
Xorg
& some other stuff
```

The same stuff happened with **Q4Wine**, **Wine, Wine-Stable, Wine64**. But Winetricks asks to remove only  `Mesa, Ubuntu-desktop, Ubuntu-desktop-minimal, Xorg`.

Any tips on how to solve this issue???

---

Outputs @N0rbert requested:

```
apt-cache policy jq wine playonlinux xserver-xorg-core wine
jq:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.6-1
  Version table:
     1.6-1 500
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
wine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
playonlinux:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.3.4-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4.3.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-core:
  Installed: 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2
  Candidate: 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2 500
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
wine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
```

---

```
        grep -ir "^deb" /etc/apt/ --include=*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```

---

Here is the Terminal output:

```
user@user:~$ sudo apt install playonlinux
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 playonlinux : Depends: jq
               Depends: mesa-utils but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python-wxgtk3.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
user@user:~$ sudo apt install q4wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  git-man gnome-video-effects gstreamer1.0-gtk3 libabw-0.1-1 libatkmm-1.6-1v5
  libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libcolamd2 libe-book-0.1-1 libepubgen-0.1-1 liberror-perl
  libestr0 libfastjson4 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libglu1-mesa libgtkmm-3.0-1v5
  libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libreoffice-base-core libsigc++-2.0-0v5
  libsuitesparseconfig5 libwps-0.4-4 lp-solve python3-netifaces x11-apps
  x11-session-utils xbitmaps xinit
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  icoutils libgpg-error-l10n libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite
Suggested packages:
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl fuseiso winetricks
Recommended packages:
  wine | wine-development | wine1.6 | wine1.8 | wine1.9 | wine2.0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cheese gdbserver git gnome-system-monitor google-chrome-stable libc6-dbg
  libfprint-2-tod1 libnetplan0 libreoffice-calc libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-writer lshw mesa-vulkan-drivers netplan.io
  rsyslog simple-scan ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-minimal
  ubuntu-standard uuid-runtime xorg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  icoutils libgpg-error-l10n libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite q4wine
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 23 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3.178 kB/3.347 kB of archives.
After this operation, 462 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
user@user:~$ sudo apt install winetricks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  x11-apps x11-session-utils xbitmaps xinit
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cabextract fonts-wine fuseiso libcapi20-3 libfaudio0 libgpg-error-l10n
  libmspack0 libodbc1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsndio7.0
  libstb0 libvkd3d1 libwine p7zip p7zip-full wine wine64
Suggested packages:
  libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc unixodbc-bin libportaudio2 sndiod
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad ttf-mscorefonts-installer p7zip-rar q4wine winbind
  playonlinux wine-binfmt dosbox exe-thumbnailer | kio-extras wine64-preloader
  tor unrar-free | unrar
Recommended packages:
  libosmesa6 wine32
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mesa-vulkan-drivers ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal xorg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cabextract fonts-wine fuseiso libcapi20-3 libfaudio0 libgpg-error-l10n
  libmspack0 libodbc1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsndio7.0
  libstb0 libvkd3d1 libwine p7zip p7zip-full wine wine64 winetricks
0 upgraded, 20 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 29,0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 226 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: can't reproduce on fresh 20.04 LTS. Please add the output of `apt-cache policy jq wine playonlinux xserver-xorg-core wine` with `grep -ir "^deb" /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert - I don't think the problem is with repositories. Other stuff works just fine.

Comment: @N0rbert - Added outputs...

Comment: The problem was solved after I changed the repository to the Main Server... I still don't know what the problem was, though. You can close the question.

Comment: If I had to guess, your system was not up-to-date and you were trying to install new software. The problems didn't have as much to do with the new software as it was the package management system was/is a mess.  You should always run `sudo apt update` before any other actions in `apt` and you should run `sudo apt upgrade` before installing new software